# Where to find an enumeration of error codes in AWSSDK.S3 for .NET

Tags: aws-sdk-net

The possible S3 error codes are listed in the docs here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_Error.html

Are they enumerated in the SDK somewhere? If so, where?